# How change python module path?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use the Scrapy Python module and because I have anaconda installed, scrapy is installed. However, I don't want to use the anaconda environment I want to use VSCode. I type "pip install scrapy"  but it returns "Requirement already satisfied". How do I change the path way of this module because I can't run Scrapy in VSCode.

It gives me a "report missing imports" error but I already have it installed.

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall but that didn't work.

Comment: It’s not clear to me why you can’t just use anaconda environments WITH VSCode. Look into that

Comment: in vscode at the bottom in the status bar there should be a section that tells you what version of python is currently active....  if you click it should open a dropdown of python environsments available.  select the one that isn't anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to modify the module search path at runtime by modifying the sys.path variable. This allows you to store module files in any folder of your choice. Since the sys.path is a list, you can append a search-path to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all.